# How to give unique html class name using javascript not from jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in JavaScript, I want to search the number of id=heading and append unique class name to the existing class.

I have tried to do this using JavaScript but able to add only to the first heading only. 
Please refer the code-pen: https://codepen.io/restar312/pen/EqWOyV

```
var check_div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var numheading = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < check_div.length; i++) {
  if (check_div[i].id.indexOf('heading') != -1)
    numheading++;
  console.log(numheading);
  var d = document.getElementById("heading");
  d.className += numheading;
}
```

Expected class name should be class=First_heading1...class=First_heading2...class=First_heading3

Comment: Seems backwards. ID's must be unique in a page and you typically want to use common class for similar elements

Comment: as @charlietfl mentioned: IDs must be unique, so `document.getElementById("heading");` will alsways get you the first occurence of the element with that ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> document.getElementById("heading")

Will always provide you with the first element having that `id`.
[Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

`className`s do not require to be unique, yet `id`s do. So you could loop through all `div` with that `className` and assign those an unique `id` instead.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  for(var tListOfElements=document.querySelectorAll('.heading'), i=0, j=tListOfElements.length; i<j; i++){
    tListOfElements[i].id = tListOfElements[i].id || 'heading_' + i;
    tListOfElements[i].textContent = tListOfElements[i].id
  }
};
```

```html
<div class = 'heading'>A</div>
<div class = 'heading'>B</div>
<div class = 'noheading'>C</div>
<div class = 'heading'>D</div>
<div class = 'heading' id = 'wannakeepmyid'>E</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your heading have the same identical id `heading`. You should use different ids to access different DOM elements.

For example:

```
<div id="heading1" class=First_heading>
  <h1>Heading1</h1>
</div>
<div id="heading2" class=First_heading>
  <h1>Heading2</h1>
</div>
<div id="heading3" class=First_heading>
  <h1>Heading3</h1>
</div>
```